# Move the mouse using Python in a virtual machine [RESOLVED]

Tags: python, automation

I need to create an automation that performs clicks and enters information into a virtual machine. I have access to a VM where I access via RDP which is where this project needs to be running, it is a server that is always on. However, when I run it and close the VM, it generates an error because it cannot find my mouse.
I've already tried using the PyAutoGUI and Pynput libraries... I believe that regardless of the library I use, it will generate the error of not finding the mouse and keyboard due to the fact that I have closed the VM application.
Any solution?

I've already tried using the PyAutoGUI and Pynput libraries.
When I closed the RDP application, the project generates an error for not finding the mouse.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Inside the VM I opened cmd and used the command `tscon rdp-tcp#0 /dest:console` 
Below is a link for better understanding for those who have the same problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1086036/is-it-possible-to-have-a-virtual-mouse-or-keyboard
I tried using the PyAutoGui library and it didn't work, so I switched to ahk and it seems to work fine: https://ahk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/